# Python3でnumpyを用いてエラーが出ます

Tags: python, python3, numpy

Python3でnumpyを用いて以下のエラーが出て困っています。

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'0,000000'
```

arena.txtの中身は以下のとおりです。

```
1   0,000000    4,219309    4,219309    8,988674    8,988674    10,848450
2   4,219309    7,414822    7,414822    12,430150   12,430150   14,198310
3   8,000000    10,478795   10,478795   15,417747   15,417747   17,297929
1   11,000000   14,257995   14,257995   19,009302   19,009302   20,873072
```

プログラムは以下のとおりです。

```
import numpy as np    

cps,s_load,f_load,s_process,f_process,s_unload,f_unload = np.loadtxt('arena.txt', unpack=True)
```

numpyを使わない方法でも構いません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: arena.txt にある数値には `,`(カンマ)が使われていますが、これは `.`(ピリオド)ではないでしょうか？

Comment: ピリオドにしたら解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5):

数値の小数点記号に`,`(カンマ)を使っている国もあります（参照 [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F%E6%95%B0%E7%82%B9)）。

Pandas の`read_csv`は小数点の`,`に対応していて、オプションで`decimal=','`とすることで小数点記号が`,`の数値を読むことができます。今回のケースであれば、Pandas を使うと以下のように書けます。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('arena.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, decimal=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'0,000000'
```

これは、string型をfloatに変換できないと言っています。
numpyでcsvをインポートする際、デフォルトでfloatデータを指定して取得するらしいです。なので、

```
np.loadtxt('arena.txt', unpack=True)
```

を

```
np.genfromtxt("arena.txt", dtype = None, delimiter = "\t")
```

に変えればできると思われます。

https://review-of-my-life.blogspot.jp/2017/11/numpycsv.html

Answer (score 0):

数値の小数点記号がカンマ `,` になっていたのをピリオド `.` に直したところ上手くいきました。

<sub>-- [user9156 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19311/python3%E3%81%A7numpy%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99#comment17977_19311)、および[質問者さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19311/python3%E3%81%A7numpy%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99#comment17985_19311)より。</sub>